# Cannot resolve method makeText()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-toast

I'm having an issue when trying to make a toast on my DatabaseHelper class on my android project under a try/catch.
I've tried the following ways:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Toast.makeText(DatabaseHelper.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Toast.makeText(DatabaseHelper.this.getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And none of them work.

Here is the code where im trying to make the toast

```
    public void criaConta(String nome, String password){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COL2 + "," + COL3 + "," + COL4 + "," + COL5 + ") VALUES ('" + nome + "','" + password + "',0,0);");
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("ErroCriarConta", "criaConta: "+e);
    }
    //Toast.makeText(DatabaseHelper.this,"Conta Criada",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Thank you in advance for anyone willing to help.

Comment: "none of them work" - what is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: If `DatabaseHelper` is an `SqliteOpenHelper`, then it is not a `Context`, which is what you need for that first argument. You pass a `Context` into the contructor, and you could keep a field for it, but you really shouldn't be doing UI stuff from a database helper class. That should be in your `Activity`.

Comment: Krease . Its the same error for everything.

Comment: Mike M. I've thought about that but if i do the try catch in the activity which the calls the method will it catch the error from the databasehelper?

Comment: Mike M. It worked! I changed it to an activity and it works perfectly. Thank you for the tip! :)

Comment: You don't necessarily need to `catch` anything in the `Activity`. Modify your `criaConta()` method to return a success/failure value, even just a simple `boolean`.

Comment: That would've been another solution, yes. Wish i've thought about this earlier. Again, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the user Mike M. mentioned in his comment you should not be mixing user-interface related stuff with your data-management.
Instead i suggest that you have a look at the ViewModel design-pattern. Using a ViewModel class you do something like:

```
try
{
    myViewModel.insert();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("ErroCriarConta", "criaConta: " + e);
}
```

in your Activity. This lets the activity catch the error which you have previously thrown in your ViewModel class in the insert()-method.

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel
{
    // ...

    public void insert() throws Exception
    {
        db.execSQL(
            "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME +
            " (" + COL2 + "," + COL3 + "," + COL4 + "," + COL5 + ")
            VALUES('" + nome + "', '" + password + "', 0, 0); ");
    }
}
```

However I would go even further and use the repository design pattern which simply adds another abstraction layer between your data and your UI. This would allow you to have your database operations be wrapped by the repository, then call those wrapper-methods in your ViewModel to read/write data from/to your database, while your activity can access the data needed for the UI from the ViewModel.

Now I know this sounds like a lot of work for you to do, to just have your Toast show up in the right UI-context, but from experience I can say that abstracting your data is really worth it, especially for preventing or fixing bugs like yours, but also to make modifying your app at a later point a lot easier.